# Как отключить в Sublime Text 3 автозакрытие тегов?

Tags: html, sublime-text-3

Скачал Sublime Text 3, обнаружил не нужную функцию автозакрытия тегов. Подскажите, как можно ее отключить чтобы все писал я самостоятельно? Плагины не устанавливал, не нужны мне.

Comment: Советую вам отметить ответы на некоторые из ваших вопросов [**принятыми**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

Для этого зайдите в `Preferences` -> `Settings` и в правой части экрана пропишите `"auto_close_tags": false`.

Comment: Здравствуйте! В Pereferences нет Help.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда Извиняюсь, перепутал. Не в `Help`, а в `Settings`.